# sql table name with traditional Chinese language

Tags: php, ms-access, codeigniter-3

I got some trouble when execute query with traditional Chinese language, the table name is 历史皮重 and the query let say `SELECT * FROM 历史皮重`, it always return

> Error Number: S0002
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Jet database
>   engine cannot find the input table or query '历史皮重'. Make sure it
>   exists and that its name is spelled correctly.
>
> SELECT * FROM 历史皮重
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/mdb_test/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

but when i change the table name with "abc" the query works fine..
is there anyway i can do a query with the traditional chinese language? 
i do the query execution with PHP and ms.access database

Comment: The question is: Do you really need to do that? I recommend using simple English when programming.

Comment: I recommend to using ASCII when developing ... maybe the trick for your question can be to surround your table name with ` SELECT * FROM ` 历史皮重 ` (without blanks)

Comment: did you try using Square bracket to enclose your table name like `SELECT * FROM [历史皮重]` anyways try to use English name for objects

Comment: @juergend yes..i really need to do that because the database export result from 'them' is using traditional chinese language, and it seems not possible for me to change every row and table name with english version everytime 'they' send the update data..

@donald123 yes,i already try with `历史皮重 ` (without blanks) and also [历史皮重 ] , the result still the same